# How to move game object transform with a clip of animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ledge climbing system which is working in a mechanical way, but not with the animation. I have position 1, where my character starts climbing and that is the place animation starts. Player then teleports to position 2 on top of the ledge, which is when animation ends. However, all of the animation plays on position 1, not from position 1 to position 2. My character shouldn't be teleporting, but smoothly climbing to a ledge. Since I don't see an option to do that in code, can I somehow move transform of my player game object a little on the y axis every clip of the animation?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate root motion curves to make an animation move as an offset or difference, rather than between 2 static points. On the animator component there is a boolean for "Apply root motion".

[Here a quick official Unity video for authoring root motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn6jxLWA31M) in case you get stuck

Comment: There is no "Generate root motion curves" option in my animations. There is "Apply root motion" in animator, but when I do that, nothing happens. I forgot to mention that my game is 2D platformer, so I think my animations don't have curves, if that is the problem. Is there another way to do this, without root motion?

Comment: Please consider watching the video linked above all the way through @Mactadilis It is an official Unity tutorial on root motion specifically.